# mediaPlayer setDataSource doesn't work

Tags: android

I try to add a video on my Android application, like the page : [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

But There are errors :

[image]

For example, why this line doesn7t work :

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
```

And this line too :

```
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
```

I don't understand because it's the developer.android.com example.
Can you help me to make understand.

Thank you (and if my question is stupid, I am sorry).

Comment: What error appears? write a message you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setDataSource(String)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)) throws `IOException` and `IllegalArgumentException` that  you are not catching. You should wrap the two calls around a `try-catch` block

Answer (score 1):

Be more attentive and read error message: **"Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException"**. So, all you need is **try-catch** block

Answer (score 0):

As other two answers suggest, your code needs to be surrounded with try/catch block. Also, if it is fetched from the web it would be in best practice to use

```
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Hope it helped, hope that your program works. However, a few minutes later i found out that prepareAsync() method is not recommended for playing mp3 files

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
if(mediaPlayer != null ){

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){mediaPlayer.stop();}

                    mediaPlayer.reset(); //this line is important!

                    String path = File.separator + "sdcard" + File.separator + utilsFields.repoDirRoot + File.separator + media.mp4;


                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                    }catch (Exception ignored){}


                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    }catch (Exception ignored){}

                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
```

Comment: mediaplayer needs to reset its configuration before setting new source parameters.